# Unit testing for grpc python client

Tags: python, pytest, grpc, grpc-python, pytest-mock

I have created python grpc client to communicate with java grpc server and have implemented one grpc api from client side.

```
self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
                self.host, options=[("grpc.lb_policy_name", "round_robin")]
            )
            self.blocking_stub = contacts_pb2_grpc.ExampleServiceStub(self.channel
```

and invoked the grpc api by following call

```
def create_call(self, request):
    return self.blocking_stub.createCall(
        request, metadata=add_meta_data(self), timeout=self.deadline_seconds
    )
```

my question here is I want to mock the create_call and need to get the response back
so I have created python service implementation.

I want to make sure the service code is called whenever I made create_call in unitest .In java we have something like this.

```
 String serverName = InProcessServerBuilder.generateName();

 grpcCleanup.register(
        InProcessServerBuilder.forName(serverName)
            .directExecutor()
            .addService(ServiceImplTestHelper.serviceImpl)
            .build()
            .start());
 channel =
        grpcCleanup.register(InProcessChannelBuilder.forName(serverName).directExecutor().build());
```

Can someone suggest how we can do this in python ?